# Configuring Cygwin Path variable to find Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I am attempting to set up my PC to use the Android NDK for my projects.
I have Cygwin installed. And I downloaded the Android NDK. Let's say I put the NDK in the following folder on my PC:

```
c:\Android_ndk\<android ndk folder in here>
```

How can I configure Cygwin's path to find the ndk? I am thinking the following may be partially correct:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/C/Android_ndk/<android ndk folder in here>
```

However I am not even sure I have my slashes the right way round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto  `..\cygwin\home\Eclipse`. You will find a file named `.bashrc`. Open it using notepad and at the end of the file add

`export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Android_ndk/<android ndk folder in here>`

If you have done everything correctly the on issuing `which ndk-build` command on cygwin terminal will give you

`/cygdrive/c/Android_ndk/<android ndk folder in here>/ndk-build`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I didn't use notepad, but typed the export command into the Cygwin terminal. Then I checked which ndk-build and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: The change to PATH is **not** persisted between Cygwin sessions. You still want this to be a part of your environment every time you start Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I changed accoridngly. But I'm actually running ndk-build through cmd.exe now. It's just easier.

Comment: Idealy it should be added to `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/78929

Answer (score 4):

With latest NDK r8b you don't need cygwin at all! Use **ndk-build.cmd** from Windows command line or in eclipse.

Comment: First add native support to your Android app, then gp to Properties C++ build, and instead of defau build command write ndk-build.cmd with full path

Answer (score 0):

add such code in .bashrc

```
 NDK=D:/android/android-ndk-r9
 PATH=${NDK}:$PATH
 ANT=C:/bin/apache-ant-1.9.2
 PATH=${ANT}/bin:$PATH
 export PATH NDK
```