# ndk-build path set, But Cygwin says ndk-build file not found

Tags: android, sdk, path, android-ndk

```
"bash: ndk-build: command not found"
```

Ok I've been dealing with this issue for 5 hours now and It's driving me crazy. I have downloaded and istalled Cygwin and Android NDK. I've set my PATH variables

```
C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r8e\    <-- in my path..
```

But it keeps telling me COMMAND NOT FOUND.

I tried putting the ndk-build.cmd ITSELF in the cywin folder but it stil lsays file not found. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring Cygwin Path variable to find Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455254/configuring-cygwin-path-variable-to-find-android-ndk)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run cmd.exe, and type in "ndk-build". Cygwin is not necessary for the latest version of NDK.